# EF6 - Many-to-One Relationship not working

Tags: c#

I have Products, Sub products, and more tables. You can see in the code, relationship not working I want it Product Class relationship with SubProduct but always the collection count is 0.
Product Class:

```cs
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

public bool Status { get; set; } = true;

public string StockCode { get; set; }

public int StockDecrease { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }

public int Amount { get; set; }

public int Desi { get; set; }

public string Barcode { get; set; }

public long Gtin { get; set; }

public string InvoiceName { get; set; }

public string EInvoiceName { get; set; }

public string Subtitle { get; set; }

public byte Kdv { get; set; }

public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<SubProduct> SubProducts { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<ProductVariant> ProductVariants { get; set; }
```

Sub Product Class:

```cs
public int Id { get; set; }
public int ProductId { get; set; }
public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
public string StockCode { get; set; }
public virtual ProductBrand Brand { get; set; }
public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
public Abstract.Marketplace Marketplace { get; set; }
public string Barcode { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string SubTitle { get; set; }
public bool IsConnected { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
public decimal PriceDiscount { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<SubProductVariant> SubProductVariants { get; set; }
```

Repository Base:

```cs
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TEntity> GetAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
{
    await using var context = new TContext();
    return await context.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

[image: Result image, I cant attach image because of 10 reputation.]

Comment: To hydrate navigation properties you have to do `.Include(x => x.SubProducts)`.

Comment: @41686d6564 I've checked the database with the correct product id.

Comment: @juharr I have a Repository Base how can do this?

Comment: it didn't give any error.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to first study more about how to handle  related entities.
You basically need to tell EF to load them in.
See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

Simplest example would something like this:

```
    // Load all products.
var products= context.Products
                    .Include(b => b.SubProducts)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have the Repository Base example in my question. How can I do this in this Repository base?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add using System.Data.Entity; to get the version of Include that takes in a lambda.

using System.Data.Entity;

```
query.Include(x => x.SubProducts)
```

and for more use ThenInclude or Include extention methods.

To define a method on the repository for this, you can use this example:

```
        public static IQueryable<TSource> GetIQueryableWithIncludes<TSource>(Expression<Func<TSource, object>>[] includeProperties, IQueryable<TSource> result)
    {
        var newResult = result;
        if (includeProperties.Any())
        {
            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
            {
                newResult = newResult.Include(includeProperty);
            }
        }

        return newResult;
    }
```

You can now pass a list of lamba expression like  p => p.SubProjects to specify what you want to include.

You can further hide this by making an GetAll method that hides these includes from the outside user of your Domain

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have the Repository Base example in my question. How can I do this in this Repository base?

Comment: are you change (this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; ) in context ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved with .Include() thanks for helping.

```cs
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TEntity> GetAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, Expression<Func<TEntity,object>> include=null)
{
    await using var context = new TContext();
    return await context.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter).Include(include).SingleOrDefaultAsync(filter);
}
```